Database snapshot replication Invalid object name, Wipe of all data
We have created new publication and then subscription replicate data from D to E database.
Publication is set to run every 10 seconds
Subscription is set to run continuously.
It was working fine and now suddenly we have started getting following issues

Data are disappearing (after every 10 seconds, seems to be matching with publication scheduled time
At some point we are also getting "Invalid object name" which means, table is recreated on destination databases

We have created around 9 subscriptions with different databases, issue is only for database D to E.
We compared all the tables scripts to identify if there are any discrepancies which may be causing this issue, but no issues there as well.
We have recreated the subscription, reinitialized the subscription but no luck.
In SQL Server Agent, I can see 2 jobs, i.e. one for publication and one for Subscription. When I disable publication Job, issue is getting resolved but now how come new data will be then get updated in subscription database.
I am not sure what is missing out here.

what kind of replication is this? Snapshot, merge, transactional? You didn't specify that.

It is snapshot, now added in title

Check the Action if name is in use property of the actual publication article. See if you want to set it to Keep existing object unchanged to avoid table being recreated each time.

